# Wordpress dynamic pagination separator

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm building a custom wordpress theme and I have a small problem with pagination separator.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
    <?php if ((get_adjacent_post(false, '', false)) && (get_adjacent_post(false, '', true))) echo ' | '; ?>
    <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
```

Here is how it should work:
On the first page only "Older Entries" link should be present with no separator, on the last page only "Newer Entries" with no separator should be displayed. On all the other pages " | " separator should be displayed between "Newer Entries" and "Older Entries" links.

Right now everything works fine with one little problem: on the first page separator is displayed behind "older entries" link.
I would like to remove the separator from the first page, so that it only shows up when both links are present on the page.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code to this and it works:

`if(get_adjacent_post(false, '', true) && is_paged()){ echo ' | '; };`

What I did is add `is_paged();` to know whether it was the front page of my blog or not.